# How is the cartesian product $E^F$ defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

For arbitrary sets $E, F$, how is $E^F$ defined? It seems to be the set of all maps from $F$ to $E$, i.e. $E^F := \{\phi : \phi\colon F \rightarrow E\}$? Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; however, this is not the Cartesian product. The Cartesian product of two sets, $A$ and $B$ - denoted "$A\times B$" - is the set of *pairs* $(a, b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

$E^F$ can be thought of as a (possibly infinitary) Cartesian product - the *Cartesian power*: $E\times E\times E\times . . . $ with "$F$-many" factors of $E$. This takes some thought to make precise, though.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is basically "yes", but I consider this to be a *construction*, not a definition. I would also consider the description of $A\times B$ as the set of ordered pairs $\{(a,b)\mid a\in A,\ b\in B\}$ to be a construction, not a definition. The reason for this is that these constructions do not always give the "correct" notion of product when applied to objects more complicated than sets.

If $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of sets indexed by some (possibly infinite) set $I$, the Cartesian product
  $$\prod_{i\in I} A_i$$
is the (necessarily unique up to unique isomorphism) pair $(X,\{\pi_i\}_{i\in I})$ consisting of a set $X$ and a family of functions $\pi_i:X\to A_i$ satisfying the following universal property: for any other pair $(Y, \{\sigma_i\}_{i\in I})$ of the same type, there is a unique function $h:Y\to X$ such that $\pi_i\circ h = \sigma_i$ for all $i\in I$.

You can check that the set of functions $X = \{\phi \mid \phi:F\to E\}$ together with the functions $\{\pi_f\}_{f\in F}$ defined by $\pi_f(\phi) = \phi(f)$ satisfies this universal property for the collection $\{E_f\}_{f\in F}$ where each $E_f$ is a copy of $E$.

Comment: -1: I think this answer will just make things more confusing for someone studying elementary set theory for the first time. Language like "universal property" and "unique isomorphism" is only useful once someone's developed a good deal of intuition. Not to mention that the crucial idea of working inside an arbitrary category is missing from this answer: what do you mean by "function," "isomorphism," etc.?

Comment: @user28111 You're certainly entitled to your opinion, but I don't think a downvote is warranted for a correct answer which may be helpful either to the OP in the future or to others.

Comment: +1: Admittedly, it wasn't a helpful answer, I simply don't understand it at my level, but still thanks for your effort.